# How do I replace double quote?

Tags: python, replace, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings and I would like to replace the " at the last two strings

```
"racist superman"|"rudy"|"mancuso"|"king"|"bach"|"racist"|"superman"|"love"|"rudy mancuso poo bear black white official music video"|"iphone x by pineapple"|"lelepons"|"hannahstocking"|"rudymancuso"|"inanna"|"anwar"|"sarkis"|"shots"|"shotsstudios"|"alesso"|"anitta"|"brazil"|"Getting My Driver's License | Lele Pons"
```

My code looks like this, it does however replace the "" from the other strings and removes the "|".

Note: the input tags_str for the function is received by a file

```
def extract_tags(tags_str):

     b = [n.strip('""').strip().replace('""', '') for n in tags_str.split("|")]
     return b

['racist superman', 'rudy', 'mancuso', 'king', 'bach', 'racist', 'superman', 'love', 'rudy mancuso poo bear black white official music video', 'iphone x by pineapple', 'lelepons', 'hannahstocking', 'rudymancuso', 'inanna', 'anwar', 'sarkis', 'shots', 'shotsstudios', 'alesso', 'anitta', 'brazil', "Getting My Driver's License", 'Lele Pons']
```

As you can see the first strip gets rid of the "" and the second strip() gets rid of whitespaces. However `"Getting My Driver's License"`
still has double quotes and with the `replace('""', '')` I expect the double quotes to be replaced, but that's not the case.

The preferred output is:

```
['racist superman', 'rudy', 'mancuso', 'king', 'bach', 'racist', 'superman', 'love', 'rudy mancuso poo bear black white official music video', 'iphone x by pineapple', 'lelepons', 'hannahstocking', 'rudymancuso', 'inanna', 'anwar', 'sarkis', 'shots', 'shotsstudios', 'alesso', 'anitta', 'brazil', 'Getting My Driver's License', 'Lele Pons']
```

Edit:
Thanks for answers/comments it got fixed by  `b = [n.strip('""').strip().replace("'", '') for n in tags_str.split("|")]`
since it was a single quote instead of double.

Comment: Note that second to last element has single quote (apostrophe) in it. that's why it fall back to double quotes to enclose the string. This is really just a representation and has no effect on the string. There are no double quotes to replace.

Comment: Or, in other words, `"Getting My Driver's License" == 'Getting My Driver\'s License'`. Python prefers the former representation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the single quote (apostrophe ( ' )) you could use the " ´ " instead.
This would avoid the whole issue.